# Swap tuple elements with destructuring assignments

Tags: javascript, swap, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I thought to swap the elements of a tuple in place using destructuring assignment as follows:

```
var a = [1,2];
[a[1], a[0]] = a;
```

However, this yields `[1, 1]`.

Babel compiles this as

```
a[1] = a[0];
a[0] = a[1];
```

I would have thought this should be compiled as

```
let tmp0 = a[0];
let tmp1 = a[1];
a[0] = tmp1;
a[1] = tmp0;
```

Traceur behaves identically to babel. So I guess this is the specified behavior?

I want to swap the two elements **in place**. So is the only way...

```
let tmp = a[0];
a[0] = a[1];
a[1] = tmp;
```

But I thought the above was what destructuring assignment was supposed to let me avoid having to do.

I'm perfectly capable of reversing the order of the two elements of the array, so that is not my question. I could do something as simple as `a.push(a.shift())`, which meets the criteria of the swapping being in-place.

I'm most interested here in why destructuring doesn't work the way it seems that it ought to.

Comment: ```let a = 'A';
    let b = 'B';
    [b, a] = [a, b];
    console.log('A:', a, ', B:', b);```

Comment: I know how to swap two values. The question is how to swap the first and second element of an array.

Comment: `const a = [ 1, 2 ]; const b = a.reverse(); console.log(b);`. Than modifies `a` unfortunately.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's so hard to understand that my entire question is how to do this with **array destructuring assignment**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd just use a function to do this -

```js
const swap = ([a,b]) => [b,a];

console.log(swap([1,2])); // [2,1]
```

Of you can swap in place -

```js
const a = [1,2];

[a[1], a[0]] = [a[0], a[1]];

console.log(a); // [2,1]
```

Answer (score 4):

> I would have thought this should be compiled as
>
> ```
> let tmp0 = a[0];
> let tmp1 = a[1];
> a[0] = tmp1;
> a[1] = tmp0;
> ```

No, the values don't get retrieved before they are assigned. Or neither is a copy of `a` made from which the values are retrieved. There only is a single reference to the array; your code rather desugars to

```
{
    const tmp = a;
    a[1] = tmp[0];
    a[0] = tmp[1]; // here, tmp[1] has the "wrong" value because a===tmp
}
```

or in fact, it desugars to an iterator that iterates the array while the left-hand-side references in the `[…]` are assigned to.

Comment: Jeremy (below) claims that FireFox actually swaps.  Do the docs say what should happen? (Where?)

Comment: @Alan Jeremy used `[a[1], a[0]] = [a[0], a[1]];` (equivalent to `[a[1], a[0]] = a.slice();`) not `[a[1], a[0]] = a`.

Comment: Yes; my bad. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
var a = [1,2];
a = a.reverse();
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that. I was trying to figure out some way to do this with deconstructing assignment.

Comment: I see what you're asking.  Looking at [the description on ecmascript.org](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:destructuring), the Semantics Assignments section seems to describe copying the right-hand side to a temporary variable, which would lead me to think the intent was for the whole operation to be atomic, as you expected.  The compiled code shows this isn't atomic.  The second array element is assigned, and then the first array element is assigned, but too late, its target has already been modified.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative, you can use `slice`:

```js
var a = [1,2];
[a[1], a[0]] = a.slice();
a; // [2,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

This works in Firefox which supports destructuring:

```
(function () {
  "use strict";

  var a = [0, 1];
  [a[1], a[0]] = [a[0], a[1]];
  console.log(a);//[1, 0]
}());
```